# Dynamically create variable in scala

Tags: scala, azure, apache-spark, variables, databricks

I have a list
`w: List[Any] = List(A, B, C)`

i want to dynamically create a variable

```
 for (e <- w) {
        
        //val $e = notebook.filter(s"Name='$e'").select("Location")
        println(e)
      }
```

so three variables A,B,C should be created with their corresponding location values.

Any help is appreciated thank you

Comment: How could you use your dynamic variables.?

Comment: i want the variable to have the same value as name. I would want to use tht variables in other part of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a list of variables

```
val List(e1, e2, e3) = w.map { e =>
  println(e)
  notebook.filter(s"Name='$e'").select("Location")
}
```

or

```
val es = w.map { e =>
  println(e)
  notebook.filter(s"Name='$e'").select("Location")
}
```

and use variables (`val`s) `e1`, `e2`, `e3` or `es(0)`, `es(1)`, `es(2)`.

---

> i want the variable to have the same value as name. I would want to use tht variables in other part of the code

Then you can use a [macro annotation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html)

```
import scala.annotation.{StaticAnnotation, compileTimeOnly}
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

@compileTimeOnly("enable macro annotations")
class generateVariables(names: String*) extends StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*): Any = macro GenerateVariablesMacro.impl
}

object GenerateVariablesMacro {
  def impl(c: blackbox.Context)(annottees: c.Tree*): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    val names = c.prefix.tree match {
      case q"new generateVariables(..$ns)" => ns
    }
    val variables = names.map { case q"${name: String}" =>
      q"""val ${TermName(name)} = notebook.filter(${s"Name='$name'"}).select("Location")"""
    }
    annottees match {
      case q"$mods object $tname extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents { $self => ..$body }" :: Nil =>
        q"""$mods object $tname extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents { $self =>
          ..$variables
          ..$body
        }"""
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
@generateVariables("A", "B", "C")
object X

//scalac: object X extends scala.AnyRef {
//  def <init>() = {
//    super.<init>();
//    ()
//  };
//  val A = notebook.filter("Name=\'A\'").select("Location");
//  val B = notebook.filter("Name=\'B\'").select("Location");
//  val C = notebook.filter("Name=\'C\'").select("Location")
//}
```

Now you can use variables `X.A`, `X.B`, `X.C` (or if you `import X._` then just `A`, `B`, `C`).

Comment: i want the variable to have the same value as name. I would want to use tht variables in other part of the code

Comment: @SankeertanSamrat Then you can use a macro annotation. See update.